# Matplotlib: add_lines to colorbar with defined properties (color: OK; dotted: not OK)

Tags: matplotlib

I want to place a line at one level (e.g., 0) in the `colorbar` of a `contourf` plot with `matplotlib`.
With the following code, I can do it but not all the properties of the `contour` lines are conserved (i.e., the color and width of the line are correct, but I can't have it dotted in the colorbar).
Any idea of how to have a dotted line corresponding to a desired level in the colorbar?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x=y=range(10)
z=numpy.random.normal(0,2,size=(10,10))

surfplot=plt.contourf(x,y,z, cmap=plt.cm.binary_r)
cont=plt.contour(surfplot, levels=[0], colors='r', linewidths=5, linestyles=':')
cbar=plt.colorbar(surfplot)
cbar.add_lines(cont)

plt.show()
```

[image: Levels in colorbar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could plot a horizontal line on your color bar directly.

```
cax = cbar.ax
cax.hlines(0.5, 0, 1, colors = 'r', linewidth = 10, linestyles = ':')
```

[image: dotted color bar line]
You'll have to calculate the y-coordinate of the line based on the data and the coloramp.

Comment: Thanks @Molly, good idea! For posterity, it might be useful then to resort to things such as `set_dashes()` for the horizontal line in order to control its visual properties if the rendering within the colorbar is not optimal (was necessary in my case).

Comment: This answer made me find the Matplotlib user guide here: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html. hope it is helpful for anybody.

Answer (score 1):

Colorbar.add_lines() currently [only retains the colors and line widths](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/fed55c6/lib/matplotlib/colorbar.py#L1228-L1229).
However, you can update the line style of the new LineCollection after adding it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
plt.style.use('classic')  # to match the look in the question

x = y = range(10)
z = numpy.random.normal(0, 2, size=(10, 10))

surfplot = plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap=plt.cm.binary_r)
cont = plt.contour(surfplot, levels=[0], colors='r', linewidths=5, linestyles=':')
cbar = plt.colorbar(surfplot)
cbar.add_lines(cont)
cbar.lines[-1].set_linestyles(cont.linestyles)  # adopt the contour's line styles

plt.show()
```

[image: contour plot with dotted line also in color bar]